# How can we Integrate CMake or ndk-build into Android Studio 3.0.1? Gradle version is 4.1, android plugin version 3.0.1

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to integrate openCV 2.4.9 into my android project, integration was successfully done, but when i build the project to check the integration the this error comes

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

  > Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
  >   Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration. For more information, go to:
  >   https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/add-native-code.html
  >   Alternatively, you can use the experimental plugin:
  >   https://developer.android.com/r/tools/experimental-plugin.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

so how could i solve this problem
Note:: 
when i integrate OpenCV 3.0.1 into my android project then there was no error of this kind then why this error comes when i integrate openCV249?

please I am new to android development so give me detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use the sources of this old version of OpenCV, you still need to comply with the modern gradle build environment. The best route would be to take the **build.gradle** files from ver. 3.0.1 and apply them to 2.4.9 (try to make as few changes as possible).

This version of OpenCV was frozen at the time when NDK release was **r9d**. This is quite outdated, and it has many problems when building the app for modern devices. I would recommend to upgrade to [Android NDK r14b](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html#ndk-14b-downloads) (again, if your build fails, the minimal necessary patch is expected to be quite small). If you have courage to upgrade further - to current [Latest Stable Version (r16b)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html), you should follow the NDK documents that explain how the new Unified headers change the ndk-build configuration (Android.mk) files.